# Windows 7 Advanced Search can't find phrases

Tags: windows, search, windows-7, advanced-search

So I'm trying to run an advanced search through Windows 7. Basically, I want to find all Word documents, modified in a certain time range, containing both the word sincerely, and the phrase contingent resources. The parts finding all docx files between the date range work, but the phrase does not. I don't want anything that just says contingent, or resources, both words have to be together. The search is returning documents that contain all three cases. Is there a way around this? Here is my search string:

```
type:.docx AND datemodified:‎4/15/‎2013 .. ‎4/‎14/‎2014 AND content:"sincerely" AND content:"contingent resources"
```

I'm using quotes around the phrase, the way every search engine I've ever used works. What did Microsoft decide to use instead? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Try This- Type:.docx datemodified:4/15/2013..4/14/2014 sincerely contingent resources